# {{ form_errors(form.fieldName) }} is not working in symfony2.3

Tags: validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to show error message related to a specific form_field in twig, but it does not show anything.

I have defined error related to my formType field in validation.yml as

```
-\-\Entity\Customer:
    properties:
        address2:
            - NotBlank:
                message: 'Testing required'
```

and when I print:

```
//Controller Class
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($customer);

//Controller
return $this->render( 'MyBundle:RegistrationPages:register.html.twig', 
    array (
        'errors' => $errors,
        'form'=>$form
    )
);
```

It shows error message in:

```
//Twig
{% if errors is defined %} 
    <h1>The Form has following errors</h1> 
    {% for error in errors %} 
        {{ error.message }} 
    {% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```

outputs:

> Testing Required

but:

```
{{ form_errors(form.address2) }}
```

is not showing anything.

Comment: You mean `{{ form_errors(form.address2) }}` is not showing anything?

Comment: Yes..It shows nothing:(

Comment: <code>

return $this->render( 'MyBundle:RegistrationPages:register.html.twig', array ('errors' => $errors));

{% if errors is defined %}

<h1>The Form has following errors</h1>

{% for error in errors %}
{{ error.message }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</code>
output as Testing Required but  <code>{{ form_errors(form.fieldName) }}</code> shows nothing

Comment: Ali, we need to see more code...you're not sending the form to your template? (i.e `array ('form' => $form)`)

Comment: This question is very hard to read. Could you edit your question and add the code within your controller and the code within your template. Also, you bound the form right?

Comment: I have edited.. Also, I am sending the form object in render..

Comment: I am not binding the form with request. as, it says you can only submit the form once.

Comment: So how your form handle the request ?

Comment: $form->handleRequest ( $request ); if($request->getMethod() == 'POST' && $form->isValid()) { //Redirect }

in this way.

Comment: Edit your question and provide your entire controller code that handle the form. Symfony works for everybody, so you have an error somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in your validation file, the `NotBlank` constraint is defined on your `address2` property:

```
properties:
    address2:
        - NotBlank:
             message: 'Testing required'
```

All errors on that form field will therefore be available on that field:

```
{{ form_errors(form.address2) }}
```

---

*Note:* You don't have to pass the errors like this to your template:

```
//Get all errors that are attributed to the entity itself
{{ form_errors(form) }}
//Get all errors for the individual field `address2 `
{{ form_errors(form.address2) }}
```

Comment: But it does not show any error message with {{form_errors(form.address2)}}:(

Comment: So, do you actually have a field called `fieldName`? Can you change `Testing required` to `address2 required` and see what you get.

Comment: No, I have field with name address2, {{ form_errors(form.address2) }} does not show antthing...

Comment: Now the message has changed to 'address2 required'

Comment: As @Guillaume says, you need to bind the form.

Comment: $form->handleRequest ( $request );
     
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST' && $form->isValid())
{
   //Redirect
}

Answer (score 2):

**In short : if you just validate the object, but not the form, you won't have errors in your form.**

If you do `$errors = $validator->validate($customer);` you validate the `$customer` not the form. So the errors are not attached to the form, they are just returned and you have to send them to the template the way you do in your question.

If you want to validate the form and to be able to access the errors in the form object, use `$form->isValid();` (I cannot show you more because I don't have your form code.)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-and-forms

Comment: @Guillaume Royer I am calling $form->isValid() with my form, still I am unable to get the error related to the field.

Comment: @AliHassan so please provide your code with `$form->isValid();` so we can answer the question. With the code you posted, this is normal if it does not work.

Comment: I have three different FormTypes  (customer, user ,Membership), i call all three FormTypes to create a single consolidated form. I have applied field validators on the respective fields in the respective FormTypes, when i submit the consolidated form delibrately with an empty value the form gives me IsValid (child forms) false, but my form_errors does not work. Also the child forms returns error count 0. 

return count($this->customerForm->getErrors())

Answer (score 0):

you must render the view after $form->handleRequest($request) . That means you should write your code like this:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
$form_view = $form->createView();
```

....
....

```
return $this->render( 'MyBundle:RegistrationPages:register.html.twig', 
    array (
        'errors' => $errors,
        'form'=>$form_view
    )
);
```